# RSpec Custom Matcher to test percentages attributes in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am making a little app for myself following up the Rails Tutorial From Michael Hartl to get my skills up.

Well, the biggest difficulty for me is TDD... I start getting a bit more used to it, but at this point I face a little problem : I have a lot of repetitive tests as one of my models has many attributes that are percentages.

I refactored the tests for these attributes in the model spec file as is :

```
describe Measure do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    @measure = user.measures.build(
                fat: 35.0,
                water: 48.0,
                muscle: 25.5,
                bmi: 33.0
              )
  end

  subject { @measure }

  describe 'validations' do

    describe 'percentage attributes validations' do

      percentages = %w[bmi fat muscle water]

      percentages.each do |percentage|

        describe "#{percentage} should be a number" do
          before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, 'value') }  
          it { should_not be_valid }
        end
      end

      percentages.each do |percentage|
        describe "#{percentage} should be positive" do
          before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, -1) }
          it { should_not be_valid }
        end
      end

      percentages.each do |percentage|
        describe "#{percentage} should be less or equal to 100" do
          before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, 100.01) }
          it { should_not be_valid }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But again this is quite long and I thought making a RSspec Custom Matcher introduced in chapter 8 of the Rails Tutorials could be a good idea.

So I felt like the test could be written like this

```
describe 'percentage attributes validations' do
  its(:bmi) { should be_a_percentage }
end
```

with `be_a_percentage` the Custom Matcher. But I am stuck as I don't get how to implement it... So far I have :

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_percentage |percentage| do
  match |measure| do
    # What should I do ?
    # percentage is nil and number is the attribute value
    # I can't call be_valid on the Measure object
  end
end
```

I tried a different call

```
describe 'percentage attributes validations' do

  specify { @measure.bmi.should be_a_percentage }

end
```

I read things about custom matchers chaining but I don't get it.

This is my first post, it is long, so I thank you in advance for your help...

Answer (score 1):

This is not really answering your direct question, but as your codebase increases in size you might want to keep it the way it is and not hide the test in a `be_a_percentage` custom-defined and hidden method. Keeping it right up there, albeit slightly verbose, ensures that you know what you are testing and not have to think about what `be_a_percentage` actually means. After all, there is such a thing as negative percentages for reductions. My 2 cents..

Anyways, we could proceed to DRY your code:

```
shared_examples_for 'percentage' do |percentage|
  describe "#{percentage} should be a number" do
    before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, 'value') }  
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "#{percentage} should be positive" do
    before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, -1) }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "#{percentage} should be less or equal to 100" do
    before { @measure.send("#{percentage}=".to_sym, 100.01) }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end

describe 'validations' do
  describe 'percentage attributes validations' do

    percentages = %w[bmi fat muscle water]

    percentages.each do |percentage|
      it_should_behave_like 'percentage'
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: [RSpec Shared Examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this could be DRYer but this is as far as I can go right now

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the DRY proposal. The reason for a custom matcher question was that this `behave_like` thing would have to be repeated in every model test that has percentages as the custom matcher would be there only once.